# Instagram API get user ID with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

I'm trying to get the user ID of an Instagram user by doing a search for their username, however my page returns with:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

and also the userID returns as "00000000"

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$username=preg_replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z_]',"",$_POST['username']); // Sanitize username
$userid = getInstaID($username); //Should return the userID for the username.

function getInstaID($username) {

$searchurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q={$username}&access_token={$accessToken}";
$search_response = file_get_contents($searchurl);
$searchresult = json_decode($search_response);

foreach($searchresult->data as $user)
{
    if($user->username == $username)
    {
        return $user->id;
    }
}
return '00000000'; // Return this ID if no user is found.
}
?>
```

The output of (I had to move the three search variables out of the function + I chose a random username)

`var_dump($searchresult);`

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
        ["code"]=> int(200)
    }
    ["data"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (6) {
            ["username"]=> string(10) "s3odhunter"
            ["bio"]=> string(155) "Twitter:s3odhunter متزوج وأب لأجمل طفلين بالعالم I'm king of the jungle  Muslim The most beautiful women in the world "
            ["website"]=> string(27) "http://youtu.be/kBFWH-7pIS4"
            ["profile_picture"]=> string(75) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1104654_75sq_1370686814.jpg"
            ["full_name"]=> string(23) "سعود المخيال"
            ["id"]=> string(7) "1104654"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `foreach` construct in the `getInstaID()` function causing the error? Because if `$searchresult` really looks like what you've posted, then there should be no such error. Code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/znq-siz Results: http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/znq-siz

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it does throw an error. If it looks like this: `foreach($searchresult as $user)` PHP no longer throws and error, however the function still returns 00000000. I'll try your code and see if it works.

Comment: Okay - I found out why it doesn't work. The function is accessing global variables. Looks like I'll have to read up on variables and scopes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to double check what the API is returning you can always use https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/. It also providers the User ID of the username but without code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<i>
if ($response){
    foreach (json_decode($searchresult)->data as $username) {
$src = $item->images->standard_resolution->url;
        $username = $item->username;
      );
    }
}
</i>
```

Comment: Please, avoid just copy/paste code and elaborate your answer.